# C# Asynchronous Function Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

## Tests

I have a function f1(string, string) which takes 4 seconds to execute (irrelevant what it does). Tested this by calling f1("a", "b") in main.

Calling

```
Console.WriteLine(f1("a", "b")); 
Console.WriteLine(f1("a", "b"));
```

will wait 4 seconds for the first function to finish, prompt the return, wait another 4 seconds, prompt the second result all fine and dandy.

I've tried doing this in parallel by creating two separate anonymous threads with lambda like so:

```
new Thread(() => {Console.WriteLine(f1("a", "b")); }).Start();
new Thread(() => {Console.WriteLine(f1("a", "b")); }).Start();
```

Since I have a dual core processor and the functions are processing heavy (OS balanced this out very well) I have gotten both prompts after 4 seconds (instead of 8) so I know it worked in parallel.

## Question

How can I write a function f1Async(string, string) which would initially call f1(string, string) albeit on a different thread every time (like I've done manually in main)? In order to know what the output of f1Async will be I have to wait for the thread to finish thus calling f1Async() two times in a row will result in the function waiting for one thread to finish before moving on to the second call.

Comment: Whoa, hold on there, before you venture off in the land of multithreading, you better know the basics first... Get a book, find a tutorial, or something, you're not going to get far without it.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't see anything terribly wrong with the question in and on itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`Parallel.For`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.110).aspx). It will run multiple iterations of an action in parallel, and will wait for all iterations to finish.

If you want to run your `f1` two times asynchronously before continuing:

```
Parallel.For(0, 2, i => Console.WriteLine(f1("a", "b")));
```

Keep in mind that asynchronous data output may result in jumbled data. You should probably `lock` your `Console.WriteLine` for thread safety:

```
object synchro = new object();
Parallel.For(0, 2, i =>
{
    var output = f1("a", "b");
    lock (synchro)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
});
```

Comment: Elegant, clear and simply brilliant answer. I didn't even know about the existance of such thing like Parallel.For. The problem I posted was vastly simplified but I felt like I just missed some mechanic to sort things out.
Thanks, well earned upvote :)!